# Detecting non-wifi signals using laptop

Tags: wifi, wireless

I was thinking if it is possible to detect other RF signals in the environment using my laptop? I don't know if there are any programs which does this, but I think there might be a solution for this, perhaps by working on wifi drivers.
I'd be thankful if anybody helps me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are programs that do this, i.e. [Metageek](http://www.metageek.com/products/wi-spy/). I have also seen people build their own home-brew spectrum analyzer if you are so inclined.